# Android permissions ask something I don't want

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, android-manifest

I'm making a React-Native app and in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I ask some things :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

As you can see, I never ask my app to access to the contacts.
However, when I build my app, she ask me the permission to access to my contacts.

Have you an idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Prolly one of the used libraries add it ...

Comment: Dependencies can add own permissions. You need to check your *merged* manifest file which contains all the additional entries from all dependencies as well.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I think about that, but no one of other AndroidManifest file has the permission for the contact access... I don't know where to find it if it's not in the manifest

Comment: @Gargantua What about the sub-dependencies of your dependencies? Did the merged manifest show anything?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I check everything but I still cannot where the permission come from...

Answer (score 1):

You can check which dependency has added the permission by looking at the
`android/app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt` log.